# Transaction's response time higher in Vugen than in browser

Tags: json, performance-testing, httpresponse, loadrunner, vugen

I am performance testing a map based web application, where a query gets fired onto the DB and in return a tabular data and map appears. Sort of like Google Maps. The problem i suppose is with rendering. While the time taken to actually "see" a table on the browser is around 1 minute, the same transaction takes around 3 minutes to complete in Vugen. 
While advance tracing the logs, it shows a JSON response (of the above mentioned table) is getting downloaded. This response is of 6 Mb and is delaying the transaction to complete. I have been careful that no asynchronous calls are going along with this GET call and is actually covered with the lr_start_transaction and lr_end_transaction which is causing this high response time.
I understand that we might get better response over client side activities using TruClient protocol or others, but there is a restriction over it and Web HTTP protocol needs to be used. 
I am using HP LR 12.02 version, over WinInet capture level. 
My question is, is there any way i can actually emulate that "1 minute" time that a user would actually need to "see" the tabular data, rather than the 3 minutes it is taking. its okay if i disregard this JSON response and not download this 6 Mb data, if it makes any difference. 
Any suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think that the web request in the script should also take 1 minute unless some client optimizations were made. Is it using HTTP/2? It is hard to tell what the problem is without going over the use case but I would try to work in the direction of finding out what is the difference between what the browser is doing and what your script is doing.

Comment: Try running the same request via an http client such as Postman and compare it to both cases.

Comment: Also make sure you are comparing the times without Wasted Time in Web protocol

Comment: Is your client displaying the data while it is in the process if being te, but before it is fully downloaded?

Comment: Break out all of the individual requests using automatic transactions for this page.  Also, make sure that you are restricting your operations to servers you own or manage.  If you have third party components delays there may be slowing your final page time down.   It would be interesting to look at the waterfall for the page to see how many requests are running parallel or following your large data request.

Comment: @Buzzy the request is using HTTP/2. I wont be able to run through Postman though, as it uses COR model (its preceeded with a OPTIONS request and some headers). Also I am not comparing the times with including Wasted Time.

Comment: @JamesPulley I have broken out all individual requests by converting into URL mode and there are no third party components, not even EXTRARES. And yes, the client browser is displaying the data first and keeps on downloading in the background. I want to measure the time the user is first able to see this response and not the background time it takes to download the remaining response.

Comment: @JayantSharma if I remember correctly, HTTP/2 was not supported until 12.52. Could you please update to the latest version and try again.

Comment: As you are trying to answer a question which can only be addressed at the GUI portion of the application layer of the OSI model (due to the use of the data before download is completed) then you need a virtual user model which can sample at that level.  You have several options: Citrix, RDP, GUI, TruClient.   In my case I would combine just a handful of GUI Virtual Users with the HTTP virtual users.   Also, you seem to be running very late to answer a question in single user performance during a multiple user test.  Unless you know it scales for one, you cannot answer the scaling for many

Comment: @JamesPulley Thinking about scaling now, I am thinking of trying it on multiple systems (not load test) but manual walkthrough. Lets see if multiple locations has any effect on this. I just have a hint that CDN might be a culprit here. I will check on this and get back to you.

Comment: The issue was with CDN. since there were no local resources available, so the response time taken to download pages at my location was higher compared that to the US. When i tried the same script from US machines, the response times were much better. Anyway, thanks all for help!